# increase node size vis.js

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I have a problem with vis.js, I cannot increase the size of a node and the font of its label.

```
nodes.push({id: el, label: currentNode.hostName,font: {color:'#FF9900', face:'courier',size:300}, group: "Domain", color:{background: getColor(currentNode) , border: getColor(currentNode) }, value: 10000, title: label,labelHighlightBold: true, borderWidthSelected: 7 });


Domain: {
                shape: 'triangleDown',
                shapeProperties: {

                      useImageSize: false,

                      size:3333
                    }

            }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

you can define the font size inside the option for creating the network

```
var options = {
    nodes : {
        shape : 'dot',
        size : 15,
        color : '#ECBF26', // select color

        font : {
            size : 16,
            color : '#ffffff'
        },
        borderWidth : 2
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I know its a little late, but I just started working with viz.js so you can do it like this:

Assuming you have your nodes save in NODES

NODES.update({ id: yourNodeId, size: 100 });

With the same method you can pretty much change anything (except for theid, which I havent been able to change like this yet) on your nodes or edges.

You can find that here, although I must admit that I ve seen better documentation for a library.

http://visjs.org/docs/data/dataset.html

Comment: I'm looking to set node sizes for one by one manually, how can i do that ?